# ssh port forwarding without logging in

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I am forwarding a port of a remote server to my local mac as follows:

```
ssh -L 15672:localhost:15672 me@example.com
```

When I do this in a shell, I am also logged into example.com. Yet I would like the command to return and not occupy my shell.

Is there an option to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should add `-N` to avoid getting a shell on the remote, and `-f` to move the process to the background without losing it if you close the shell.

Comment: great. That was quick. I will accept when stackexchange let's me.

Comment: The command is `ssh -L 3000:localhost:3000 -Nf remote-host`